Calling google api from nodeJS backend without UI
I am trying to call google mail api from nodeJS application but getting GaxiosError.
useing service account key saved in auth.json
code snippet =>
const { gmail, gmail_v1, auth } = require('@googleapis/gmail');
const key = require('./auth.json');

async function main() {
    const jwt = new auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, [
        'https://mail.google.com/',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata'
    ]);
    jwt.authorize(async (err, res) => {
        const { access_token } = res;

        const api = new gmail_v1.Resource$Users$Messages({
            google: {
                _options: {}
            },
            _options: {
                rootUrl: 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/'
            }
        });
        try {
            const k = await api.list(
                {
                    auth: `Bearer ${access_token}`,

                    userId: '********@gmail.com'
                },
                {}
            );
            console.log(k);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
main();


I want to be able to fetch list of user messages without using OAuth login i.e. using gui application.

thats not how you use service accounts https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest
